# How to pass TeamCity parameter to Maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

I'm currently evaluation TeamCity 8.

We got several branches (master, development + feature branches) and a Artifactory setup.
If the master/development snapshots are build successfully, they are being deployed to Artifactory. The problem is, that the feature branches get deployed into the development repository too.

I couldn't find a way to tell the artifactory plugin to ignore the other branches, but there is an option to include/exclude certain artifacts through their filename.
However, the artifacts of the feature branches don't have any special naming.

Is there a way, to get the name of the branch into the pom.xml, so i could use it as a prefix for the artifact name? I found TeamCity variables like "teamcity.build.branch" but couldn't figure out how to include them, so that teamcity replaces them.

Does someone know how (or even a better way) to do this?

Comment: If you created the branch you should have changed the version. But it sounds as you didn't do so. You could use buildnumber-maven-plugin to get the information about the branch (svn, git) so this might help. Apart from that i don't see a problem if feature branches will be deployed to repo only if they have the same versions as the master/trunk. But this brings me to the start this entry.

Comment: By changing the version manually, let's say, i set the version of the feature branch to "1.0.0-F16-SNAPSHOT", work on it and finish.

I open a new pull request and wait for approval.

Now, the version is "1.0.0-F16-SNAPSHOT" and i want to merge into  development. If i merge using stash, the wrong version number gets pushed into development, the CI server picks it up and the wrong artifact gets pushed into artifactory. If i commit a new version number before merging, the CI server may pick it up before i can finish the merge and the totally wrong artifact gets pushed into artifactory too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The teamcity.build.parameter exposed by teamcity is a configuration parameter. To change it into a system /env parameter , in your build parameters , define a a system parameter whose value is always going to be %teamcity.build.parameter%

You can pass in properties into build files using system parameters . You can use the ${env.my_parameter}  construct to get this value  if it is an env variable or a ${system_parameter} construct to get its value if you define it as a system parameter